# How to calculate linear index of fuzziness of an image?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, software-implementation, quality-factor

i am trying to calculate  linear index of fuzziness of an image using this formula:[image: formula]
i have to see a positive value according to the paper. But i see a negative value, so i think i am doing something wrong. here is my try.

```
q=(pi/2)*(1-output_image/255); %I is output image and 255 is maximum gray level
y= sum(sum(min(q,1-q)))/(width*height); %M*N is width*height
```

Comment: can you provide your full script? the snippet seems to work OK for me

Comment: sure (https://0bin.net/paste/fIuUuRYHgoHnuemT#V4VvSGj9YW+dhO7BcGq3WNWlVwJLCj3bXBgmDwY3BSj

Comment: do you think the 'output_image' should be cast into uint8 before being used in the formula?

Comment: `output_image` is `double` in this formula. when i cast it to `uint8` , `y` equals to 0.

Comment: @beyblade41, Could you review my answer?

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB it would be something like:

```matlab
mI = imread('SomeImage.png');
mI = im2double(mI);
mI = mI(:, :, 1); %<! Working on a single channel

% For RGB do it per channel
maxVal = max(mI(:));
mQ = ((pi / 2) * (1 - (mI ./ maxVal)));
mGamma = mean(min(mQ, 1 - mQ), 'all');
```

The above is for grayscale image (Single channel).